# Derivation of the volume preserving mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

> [image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Picture above is from 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007)..

I want to get the (2) from (1) . First , choice a positive function $\varphi(t)$ such that the volume enclosed by  surface $\widetilde M_t$ given by 
$$
\widetilde F(x,t) = \varphi(t)F(x,t) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(3)
$$
is equal to the volume enclosed by $M_0$. So I have 
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}\int _U \widetilde F(x,t)\cdot \widetilde\nu(x,t) \sqrt{\widetilde g(x,t)} dx =\frac{1}{n+1}\int_U F(x,0)\cdot \nu(x,0) \sqrt{g(x,0)} dx          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(4)
$$
And 
$$
\widetilde g_{ij}=\varphi^2 g_{ij}   
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\widetilde h_{ij}=\varphi h_{ij}  \\
~~~~~~\widetilde H=\varphi^{-1} H   
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\sqrt{\widetilde g}= \varphi^n\sqrt{g}~~~~  \\
~~~~~~~\widetilde\nu(x,t)   =\nu(x,t) 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\partial_t \nu(x,t)=\nabla H(x,t)  \\
\partial_t\sqrt g =-H^2 \sqrt g~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$$
Differentiate (4), I have 
$$
0=\int_U (n+1)\varphi^n\varphi' F\cdot\nu\sqrt g - \varphi^{n+1} H \sqrt g 
+\varphi^{n+1}F\cdot \nabla H \sqrt g   -\varphi ^{n+1} F\cdot\nu H^2 \sqrt g  
dx
$$
so I have 
$$
\frac{\varphi ' }{\varphi} =\frac{1}{n+1} \frac{\int_U (H-F\cdot \nabla H +F\cdot \nu H^2 )\sqrt g}{\int_U F\cdot \nu \sqrt g }
$$
define $h(t)$ as
$$
h(t)\triangleq\frac{\int_U (H-F\cdot \nabla H +F\cdot \nu H^2 )\sqrt g}{\int_U F\cdot \nu \sqrt g }
$$
introduce a new time
$$
\widetilde t (t) = \int _0^t  \varphi^2(\tau) d\tau
$$
so I have 
$$
\frac{d\widetilde t}{dt}=\varphi^2(t)  ~~~~~~~~~~~  \frac{d t}{d\widetilde t}=\varphi^{-2}(t(\widetilde t))
$$
So , I have 
$$
\partial_{\widetilde t} \widetilde F =\partial _t \widetilde F \varphi^{-2}
=\varphi^{-2}[\partial_t\varphi F+\varphi \partial_t F] 
=\varphi^{-1}Fh-\varphi H\nu
=\widetilde F\widetilde h-\widetilde H \widetilde \nu 
$$
So , I have the volume preserving mean curvature flow 
$$
\partial_t F =Fh-H\nu
$$
In fact, it really be preserving volume. Because 
$$
\partial_t \int _U F\cdot \nu \sqrt g dx  =0
$$
But it is not same with (2) in above picture. How to get the (2) ? I think the form of (2) is better than mine.

**PS**: After long time, I can't deal it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: As I calculation, it is volume preserving MCF, just has a bad form. For getting Huisken's volume preserving MCF, you can refer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196667/how-to-show-then-the-enclosed-volume-changes-by-dv-dt-int-f-da-when-a-surfa